# You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'name' to comment without a default

Tags: python, django, django-models

Error ```You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'name' to comment without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:

1. Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
2. Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
   Select an option: ```

**models.py**

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.urls import reverse
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
    
    
    
    
    class Post(models.Model):
        published = None
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        )
        body = models.TextField()
        header_image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="images/", default='fox.jpeg')
    
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
    
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('post_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
    
    
    class Comment(models.Model):
        post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        body = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    
    
        def __str__(self):
            return '%s - %s' % (self.post.title, self.name)
```

i tried and without *blank=True* and
`body = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, default='Some String')`

This error constantly pops up,
I would be grateful for any help

Answer (score 3):

you need to set a default value to populate the previous rows, add: default=""
to name attribute like this:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="Some String")
```

then make sure to run :

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: It works, thank you so much! I would be glad if you could explain in more detail what and how, otherwise I do not quite understand

Comment: Hello @Squidward , According to the documentation: 
- makemigrations, which is responsible for creating new migrations based on the changes you have made to your models.
- migrate, which is responsible for applying and unapplying migrations.

so when you do any modifications in your models, you need to create migrations file first using 'python manage.py makemigrations'. This will create a files in the "migrations" folder inside your app, then apply these migrations by typing "python manage.py migrate"

Comment: it's clear about that, so I did `makemigrations`